# Format a tbl within a dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add commas for thousands in my data e.g. 10,000 along with dollars e.g. $10,000.

I'm using several `dplyr` commands along with `tidyr` gather and spread functions. Here's what I tried:

Cut n paste this code block to generate the random data "dataset" I'm working with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

## Generate some data
channels <- c("Facebook", "Youtube", "SEM", "Organic", "Direct", "Email")
last_month <- Sys.Date() %m+% months(-1) %>% floor_date("month")
mts <- seq(from = last_month %m+% months(-23), to = last_month, by = "1 month") %>% as.Date()
dimvars <- expand.grid(Month = mts, Channel = channels, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# metrics
rws <- nrow(dimvars)
set.seed(42)

# generates variablility in the random data
randwalk <- function(initial_val, ...){
  initial_val + cumsum(rnorm(...))
}
Sessions <- ceiling(randwalk(3000, n = rws, mean = 8, sd = 1500)) %>% abs()
Revenue <- ceiling(randwalk(10000, n = rws, mean = 0, sd = 3500)) %>% abs()

# make primary df
dataset <- cbind(dimvars, Revenue)
```

Which looks like:

```
> tbl_df(dataset)
# A tibble: 144 × 3
        Month  Channel Revenue
       <date>    <chr>   <dbl>
1  2015-06-01 Facebook    8552
2  2015-07-01 Facebook   12449
3  2015-08-01 Facebook   10765
4  2015-09-01 Facebook    9249
5  2015-10-01 Facebook   11688
6  2015-11-01 Facebook    7991
7  2015-12-01 Facebook    7849
8  2016-01-01 Facebook    2418
9  2016-02-01 Facebook    6503
10 2016-03-01 Facebook    5545
# ... with 134 more rows
```

Now I want to spread the months into columns to show revenue trend by channel, month over month. I can do that like so:

```
revenueTable <- dataset %>% select(Month, Channel, Revenue) %>%
  group_by(Month, Channel) %>%
  summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
  #mutate(Revenue = paste0("$", format(Revenue, big.interval = ","))) %>%
  gather(Key, Value, -Channel, -Month) %>%
  spread(Month, Value) %>%
  select(-Key)
```

And it looks almost exactly as I want:

```
> revenueTable
# A tibble: 6 × 25
   Channel `2015-06-01` `2015-07-01` `2015-08-01` `2015-09-01` `2015-10-01` `2015-11-01` `2015-12-01` `2016-01-01` `2016-02-01` `2016-03-01` `2016-04-01`
*    <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1   Direct        11910         8417         4012          359         4473         2702         6261         6167         8630         5230         1394
2    Email         7244         3517          671         1339        10788        10575         8567         8406         7856         6345         7733
3 Facebook         8552        12449        10765         9249        11688         7991         7849         2418         6503         5545         3908
4  Organic         4191          978          219         4274         2924         4155         5981         9719         8220         8829         7024
5      SEM         2344         6873        10230         6429         5016         2964         3390         3841         3163         1994         2105
6  Youtube          186         2949         2144         5073         1035         4878         7905         7377         2305         4556         6247
# ... with 13 more variables: `2016-05-01` <dbl>, `2016-06-01` <dbl>, `2016-07-01` <dbl>, `2016-08-01` <dbl>, `2016-09-01` <dbl>, `2016-10-01` <dbl>,
#   `2016-11-01` <dbl>, `2016-12-01` <dbl>, `2017-01-01` <dbl>, `2017-02-01` <dbl>, `2017-03-01` <dbl>, `2017-04-01` <dbl>, `2017-05-01` <dbl>
```

Now the part I'm struggling with. I would like to format the data as currency. I tried adding this inbetween `summarise()` and `gather()` within the chain:

```
mutate(Revenue = paste0("$", format(Revenue, big.interval = ","))) %>%
```

This half works. The dollar sign is prepended but the comma separators do not show. I tried removing the paste0("$" part to see if I could get the comma formatting to work with no success.

How can I format my tbl as a currency with dollars and commas, rounded to nearest whole dollars (no $1.99, just $2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just do this at the end with [`dplyr::mutate_at()`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html).

```
revenueTable %>% mutate_at(vars(-Channel), funs(. %>% round(0) %>% scales::dollar()))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 25
#>    Channel `2015-06-01` `2015-07-01` `2015-08-01` `2015-09-01`
#>      <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>
#> 1   Direct      $11,910       $8,417       $4,012         $359
#> 2    Email       $7,244       $3,517         $671       $1,339
#> 3 Facebook       $8,552      $12,449      $10,765       $9,249
#> 4  Organic       $4,191         $978         $219       $4,274
#> 5      SEM       $2,344       $6,873      $10,230       $6,429
#> 6  Youtube         $186       $2,949       $2,144       $5,073
#> # ... with 20 more variables: `2015-10-01` <chr>, `2015-11-01` <chr>,
#> #   `2015-12-01` <chr>, `2016-01-01` <chr>, `2016-02-01` <chr>,
#> #   `2016-03-01` <chr>, `2016-04-01` <chr>, `2016-05-01` <chr>,
#> #   `2016-06-01` <chr>, `2016-07-01` <chr>, `2016-08-01` <chr>,
#> #   `2016-09-01` <chr>, `2016-10-01` <chr>, `2016-11-01` <chr>,
#> #   `2016-12-01` <chr>, `2017-01-01` <chr>, `2017-02-01` <chr>,
#> #   `2017-03-01` <chr>, `2017-04-01` <chr>, `2017-05-01` <chr>
```

Comment: Hey it works! Thank you. Any chance to break it down? Never come across ``mutate_at() `` I'll look it up, but what is ``funs(.`` doing? What's the dot?

Comment: yeah, the `funs()` contains a function to apply to all the columns specified in `vars()`. The `.` in `funs()` stands in for the column name, and otherwise it works just like the content of a mutate statement. eg. `new_var = old_var %>% round(0) %>% scales::dollar()` becomes `funs(. %>% round(0) %>% scales::dollar())` And in `vars()` you use all the same [`select helpers`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_helpers.html) as with `dplyr::select()`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setdiff(names(revenueTable), 'Channel')
setDT(revenueTable)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
         scales::dollar(round(x))), .SDcols =  nm1]

revenueTable[, 1:3, with = FALSE]
#     Channel `2015-06-01` `2015-07-01`
#1:   Direct      $11,910       $8,417
#2:    Email       $7,244       $3,517
#3: Facebook       $8,552      $12,449
#4:  Organic       $4,191         $978
#5:      SEM       $2,344       $6,873
#6:  Youtube         $186       $2,949
```

Comment: Thanks for the data table offering too